# How can I modify a tag inside div with id with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got the following code:

```
<div id="header">
  <a href="http://somelink.com">white link</a>
  <a href="http://somelink.com">white link</a>
  <a href="http://somelink.com">white link</a>
  <a href="http://somelink.com">white link</a>
</div>
<div id="some_other_div>
  <a href="http://otherlink.com">unnafected link</a> ...
```

What I want to do it modify only the `<a>` tags inside the header div in a similar way to:

```
#header a {
  color:white;
}
```

using only Javascript. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same CSS selector with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method.

```
var ele = document.querySelector('#header a');
ele.style.color = 'white';
```

---

If there are multiple elements within the `div` then use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and iterate over them to update the style property. You can iterate over the collection using simple for loop or [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method with [`[].slice.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) or [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method(for converting into an array).

```
var eles = document.querySelectorAll('#header a');
[].slice.call(eles, function(ele){
  ele.style.color = 'white';
})
```

Comment: @levi :  I will add few more explanation later

Comment: no need, I have learned from it. up until I saw this answer I was using a complex `Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll() ).forEach(...)` - your answer is a good answer

Answer (score 1):

here the solution:

```
var elements = document.querySelector('#header a');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.color = 'white';
}
```